# How to to filter dict to select only keys greater than a value?

Tags: python

I have a dict with following structure:

```
{5:"djdj", 6:"8899", 7:"998kdj"}
```

The key is int typed and it's not sorted.

Now I want all the elements whose key is >= 6.

Is there easy way to do that?

Comment: Do you want a `list` where all of the values have a key in the `dict` greater-than-or-equal-to 6? Or do you want a `dict` where the there are no keys lower than 6?

Comment: It is a shame this question got closed. It asks explicitly about the key while the alleged duplicate strictly deals with values.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`[v for k,v in mydict.items() if k >= 6]`

Comment: Is it legal: {k,v for k,v in mydict.items() if k >= 6}

Comment: @Bin Chen: they're adding that syntax  (using : rather than , ) in Python 3, but for now, no.  http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/

Comment: This drops the keys. To return a dictionary, see ephemient's or bukzor's answers below.

Answer (score 12):

What do you mean by "elements"?

If you want a `dict` of key-value pairs with keys ≥6, Python 2.7+ and 3.x support *dict comprehensions*.

```
{ k: v for k, v in mydict.items() if k >= 6 }
```

You can get this in earlier versions of Python

```
dict( (k, v) for k, v in mydict.items() if k >= 6 )  # Python 2.4+
dict([(k, v) for k, v in mydict.items() if k >= 6])  # Python 2.0+
```

by using expression generators or list comprehensions.

If you want a list of keys only,

```
[ k for k in mydict.keys() if k >= 6 ]
filter( lambda k: k >= 6, mydict.keys() )
```

Similarly, if you want a list of values only,

```
[ v for k, v in mydict.items() if k >= 6 ]
[ mydict[k] for k in mydict.keys() if k >= 6 ]
map( mydict.get, filter( lambda k: k >= 6, mydict.keys() ) )
```

Comment: You meant `if`, not `where`, in your list comprehensions.

Comment: D'oh.  Obviously.  Too much SQL lately...

Answer (score 9):

It can be done with `filter` too.

```
In [9]: data = {5:"djdj", 6:"8899", 7:"998kdj"}

In [10]: dict(filter(lambda x: x[0] > 5, data.items()))
Out[10]: {6: '8899', 7: '998kdj'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[ mydict[k] for k in filter(lambda x : x > 6, mydict) ]
```

Comment: yuck, why not `in mydict if k > 6` instead of using filter?

Answer (score 2):

To get a dictionary right away: (works in both python 2 and 3)

```
dict( (k,v) for k,v in mydict.items() if k >= 6 )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the largest key and have no missing keys you can also just go through the dictonary directly: `[mydict[x] for x in range(6, largest_key+1)]`. That would be the most efficient way.

Comment: @bukzor: Then you have a lot of missing keys, so this doesn't apply. On the other hand, consider a dict with 10^9 entries where you want x < 100 - that only takes 100 lookups, instead of 10^9 comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *list comprehension*:

```
mydict = {5:"djdj", 6:"8899", 7:"998kdj"}
print [k for k in mydict if k >= 6]  # prints "[6, 7]"
print dict([(k, mydict[k]) for k in mydict if k >= 6])  # prints "{6:"8899", 7:"998kdj"}"
```

Comment: In Python 3, you can do dictionary comprehension, so the `dict([(k, mydict[k]) for k in mydict if k >= 6])` could become `{k: mydict[k] for k in mydict if k >= 6])`. Probably not helpful for this case, but cool nonetheless :-)

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension seems to be what you seek but with a list of elements as opposed to keys:

```
a = {5:"djdj", 6:"8899", 7:"998kdj"}
[a[elem] for elem in a if elem >= 6]  #should give you "['8866', '998kd']"
```