# python: how to get a subset of dict

Tags: python

I have a dict that has many elements, I want to write a function that can return the elements in the given index range(treat dict as array):

```
get_range(dict, begin, end):
    return {a new dict for all the indexes between begin and end}
```

How that can be done?

EDIT: I am not asking using key filter... eg)

```
{"a":"b", "c":"d", "e":"f"}

get_range(dict, 0, 1) returns {"a":"b", "c":"d"} (the first 2 elements)
```

I don't care the sorting...
Actually I am implementing the server side paging...

Comment: by __indexes__ you mean keys ???

Comment: @singularity: Looking at OP's past question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181367/python-possible-to-filter-dict you should be right.

Comment: NO, not by key, just after some sorting(or no sorting at all), I want the first/last/middle parts of the dict...

Comment: dictionaries don't have any order, so you can't get the 'first' 2 elements.

Comment: @Bin Chen: __first/last/middle__ you can have a different subset each time you so the subset; because see @Douglas comment , actually i think you will be better with a list of tuple rather than a dict ; just maybe :)

Comment: @Bin Chen: I think the point @singularity is making is that the dictionaries `{"a":"b", "c":"d", "e":"f"}` and `{"e":"f", "c":"d", "a":"b"}` are *the same*. What are the first two elements?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Edit:** A dictionary is *not ordered*. It is impossible to  make `get_range` return the same slice whenever you have modified the dictionary. If you need deterministic result, replace your `dict` [with a `collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Anyway, you could get a slice [using `itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
import itertools
def get_range(dictionary, begin, end):
  return dict(itertools.islice(dictionary.iteritems(), begin, end+1))
```

---

*The previous answer that filters by key is kept below:*

With @[Douglas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194365/python-how-to-get-a-subset-of-dict/4194392#4194392)' algorithm, we could simplify it by using a generator expression:

```
def get_range(dictionary, begin, end):
  return dict((k, v) for k, v in dictionary.iteritems() if begin <= k <= end)
```

BTW, don't use `dict` as the variable name, as you can see here `dict` is a constructor of dictionary.

If you are using Python 3.x, you could use dictionary comprehension directly.

```
def get_range(dictionary, begin, end):
  return {k: v for k, v in dictionary.items() if begin <= k <= end}
```

Comment: Calling the variable the_dict or such is the "proper" style for variables.

Comment: @Chris: OK. (Renamed to `dictionary` so both sides are happy :) )

Comment: The second example doesn't do the same as the first -- the first filters on the keys, the second slices the list of items.

Comment: As of Python 3.7, dictionaries are now guaranteed to preserve insertion order.

Answer (score 3):

Straight forward implementation:

```
def get_range(d, begin, end):
    result = {}
    for (key,value) in d.iteritems():
        if key >= begin and key <= end:
            result[key] = value
    return result
```

One line:

```
def get_range2(d, begin, end):
    return dict([ (k,v) for (k,v) in d.iteritems() if k >= begin and k <= end ])
```

Comment: Eek, *please* don't call the parameter `dict`... also `key >= begin and key <= end` would be neater as `begin <= key <= end`.  Cool Python feature, the way you can do that.

Comment: Just following the OP... I agree bad variable name.

Answer (score 1):

resting assured that what you really want an `OrderedDict`, you can also use `enumerate`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def get_range(d, begin, end):
    return dict(e for i, e in enumerate(d.items()) if begin <= i <= end)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print get_range({"a":"b", "c":"d", "e":"f"}, 0, 1)
```

output:

```
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

ps: I let you use `0, 1` as range values, but you should use `0, 2` to sign the "first two elements" (and use `begin <= i < end` as comparison function

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, in Python dictionaries are inherently unordered. However at any given moment a list of their current keys or key,value pairs can be obtained by using their `keys()`or `items()` methods.

A potential problem with using these lists is that not only their contents, but also the order it is returned in will likely vary if the dictionary has been modified (or mutated) since the last time they were used. This means you generally can't store and reuse the list unless you update it every time the dictionary is is changed just in case you're going to need it.

To make this approach more manageable you can combining a dictionary and the auxiliary list into a new derived class which takes care of the synchronization between the two and also provides a `get_range()` method that make use of the list's current contents. Below is sample code showing how this could be done. It's based on ideas I got from the code in [this ActiveState Python Recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52303-the-auxiliary-dictionary-idiom-for-sequences-with-/).

```
class dict_with_get_range(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwrds):
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwrds)
        self._list_ok = False

    def _rebuild_list(self):
        self._list = []
        for k,v in self.iteritems():
            self._list.append((k,v))
        self._list_ok = True

    def get_range(self, begin, end):
        if not self._list_ok:
            self._rebuild_list()
        return dict(self._list[i] for i in range(begin,end+1))

def _wrapMutatorMethod(methodname):
    _method = getattr(dict, methodname)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwrds):
        # Reset 'list OK' flag, then delegate to the real mutator method
        self._list_ok = False
        return _method(self, *args, **kwrds)
    setattr(dict_with_get_range, methodname, wrapper)

for methodname in 'delitem setitem'.split():
    _wrapMutatorMethod('__%s__' % methodname)
for methodname in 'clear update setdefault pop popitem'.split():
    _wrapMutatorMethod(methodname)
del _wrapMutatorMethod  # no longer needed

dct = dict_with_get_range({"a":"b", "c":"d", "e":"f"})
print dct.get_range(0, 1)
# {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
del dct["c"]
print dct.get_range(0, 1)
# {'a': 'b', 'e': 'f'}
```

The basic idea is to derive a new class from `dict` that also has an internal contents list for use by the new `get_range()` method it provides that regular dictionary objects don't. To minmize the need to update (or even create) this internal list, it also has a flag indicating whether or not the list is up-to-date, and only checks it and rebuilds the list when necessary.

To maintain the flag, each inherited dictionary method which potentially changes (or mutates) the dictionary's contents is "wrapped" with helper function the resets the flag and then chains to the normal dictionary method to actually perform the operation. Installing them into the class is simply a matter of putting the names of the methods in one of two lists and then passing them one at time to an auxiliary utility immediately following the creation of the class.