# How to pass members of a dict to a function

Tags: python

Suppose I have a function that I do not control that looks something like the following:

```
def some_func(foo, bar, bas, baz):
    do_something()
    return some_val
```

Now I want to call this function passing elements from a dict that contains keys that are identical to the arguments of this function.  I could do something like:

```
some_func(foo=mydict['foo'],
          bar=mydict['bar'],
          bas=mydict['bas'],
          baz=mydict['baz'])
```

Is there some elegant way I could take advantage of the fact that the keys match the parms to do this less verbosely?  I know I could pass the whole dict, but let's say I either don't want to or can't change the function to accept a single dict rather than the individual arguments.

Thanks,
Jerry

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's what `**` argument unpacking is for:

```
some_func(**mydict)
```

See also [Unpacking argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the Python tutorial.

Comment: Does this work if there are extra dict elements that aren't valid argument names?

Comment: It works if the function accepts keyword args using the `**` notation, in which case it will get the extra ones as a separate dictionary and probably ignore them. Otherwise no.

Comment: if you want to pass an unknown number of arguments, you can give your function a `**kwargs` parameter. http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/

Comment: I didn't realize you could do this in the calling end.  Thanks!

Comment: I was about 98% sure it wouldn't work, but I admit I've never used the feature. This question shows how to pare the dict down to the valid subset: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194365/python-how-to-get-a-subset-of-dict

Comment: @MarkRansom: kindall's nice answer below also shows some options.

Comment: I noticed that, and already gave my +1. P.S. congratulations on your Legendary badge!

Comment: @MarkRansom: Thanks.  (Doesn't feel too much like an achievement to me.)

Comment: Not much of an achievement? Only 68 other people have it. I've hit my 200 rep limit perhaps 5 times altogether, and you did it 150 times.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Which basically means I spend too much time on SO. :)

Comment: Legen... wait for it... dary!

Answer (score 5):

As Sven notes, you can pass a `dict` to a function using `**` unpacking. But if the `dict` contains keys that aren't argument names to the target function, this works only if the function you're calling accepts keyword arguments using the `**` notation. If it doesn't, you'll get an error.

If the function you're calling doesn't have a `**kwargs` parameter, the easiest way to handle it is to add one. But if you can't do that, you have a couple approaches:

1) Write a wrapper function:

```
def wrapper(foo, bar, baz, quux, **kwargs):
    return some_func(foo, bar, baz, quux)

wrapper(**mydict)
```

2) Write a function to extract just the dict keys you need:

```
def extract(dikt, keys):
    return dict((k, dikt[k]) for k in keys.split())

some_func(**extract(mydict, "foo bar baz quux"))
```

3) Write a function that introspects the function you're calling and extracts the keys you need from the dictionary -- basically the same as #2 except you don't have to "repeat yourself" as much.

```
def call_with_dict(func, dikt):
    func(**dict((k, dikt[k]) for k in 
         func.func_code.co_varnames[:func.func_code.co_argcount]))

call_with_dict(some_func, my_dict)
```

Note that this doesn't allow you to omit arguments that have default values in the function signature. You could do some additional introspection to permit that (the length of `func.func_defaults` determines which of the arguments have default values).

This introspection is for Python 2.x, Python 3 and later will probably need some tweaking. For this reason, I prefer one of the first two methods.

PS -- Thanks to Sven for catching my missing `**` in my second approach.

Comment: I'd suggest to use `argnames = set(inspect.getargspec(action)[0]); kwargs = {k: v for k, v in dikt.iteritems() if k in argnames}` in the inrospection version.  This works on both, Python 2.7 and 3.x (and also on earlier versions if you use `dict()` instead of the dicitonary comprehension).  I also rearranged the code to allow omitting arguments that have default values.