# forwarding method arguments to another method - self needs to be popped from locals()

Tags: python, oop

It is straightforward to delegate a called function's data to another function:

```
def test2(a, b):
    huh = locals()
    print huh

def test(a, b='hoho'):
    test2(**locals())
```

However, `locals()` contains `self` when a method is called and this gets in the way when attempting to do the same thing in a single line for method calls:

```
class X(object):
    def test2(self, a, b):
        huh = locals()
        print huh

    def test(self, a, b='hoho'):
        self.test2(**locals()) # no workie
        test2(**locals()) # no workie either
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Do you really have so many arguments that you don't want to just pass them on explicitly? Using `locals` will break at the slightest opportunity.

Comment: do you have a reference supporting the assertion that `locals` is fragile?

Answer (score 5):

You should not be using `locals()` at all here; use `*args` an `**kw` to catch arguments and pass those on:

```
def test(self, *args, **kw):
    self.test(*args, **kw)
```

Comment: One downside is that `help()` on such a function won't tell you much about what the arguments are.

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago I wrote a function that introspects the function being called and passes named arguments only for parameters that actually exist; [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9433836/416467).

But I'm with Martijn in general, passing `locals()` somewhere else smells like a bad idea.