# How to conditionally delete Keys from multiple Python dictionaries. The condition is (Value <= time.time()- 15)

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, filter

In Python 3.6, how can efficiently remove certain Keys from the three dictionaries based on whether or not their Value is 15 seconds old or older?

The three dictionaries store Integer Ids as Keys (1111, etc) and Epoch Integers as Values(915824792, etc)

```
import time

dict1 = {1111: 915824792, 2222:1053632792, 1234:2211219992, ...}
dict2 = {1114: 1291837592, 9999:1580067992, 2317:2242496792, ...}
dict3 = {1777: 1229543192, 8888:1895687192, 2319:3725639192, ...}


[v for k,v in dict1.items() if v <= (time.time()-15)] # This is not complete, idk how to conditionally delete Keys from a dictionary, and idk if my syntax is correct

   [v for k,v in dict2.items() if v <= (time.time()-15)] # This is not complete, idk how to conditionally delete Keys from a dictionary, and idk if my syntax is correct

   [v for k,v in dict3.items() if v <= (time.time()-15)] # This is not complete, idk how to conditionally delete Keys from a dictionary, and idk if my syntax is correct

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/4181492/6200445
```

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to keep 3 separate dicts, just that each one could have less elements than before, right?

Comment: yes, that is accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to build a new dict with comprehension:

```
dict1 = {1111: 915824792, 2222:1053632792, 1234:2211219992}
dict2 = {1114: 1291837592, 9999:1580067992, 2317:2242496792}
dict3 = {1777: 1229543192, 8888:1895687192, 2319:3725639192}

import time
now = time.time()
filter_v = now - 15
# 1554498239.9005954

new_dict1 = {
    k: v
    for k, v in dict1.items()
    if v <= filter_v}
# {1111: 915824792, 2222: 1053632792}
```

Repeat for each of the dicts, if you want them separate

```
new_dict2 = {
    k: v
    for k, v in dict2.items()
    if v <= filter_v}
new_dict3 = {
    k: v
    for k, v in dict3.items()
    if v <= filter_v}
```

Is that what you need?

---

If you have many dicts that you want to keep separate but filter out a few elements in each, you could use a list to hold all those dicts:

```
import time
now = time.time()
filter_v = now - 15

dict_list = [
    {1111: 915824792, 2222:1053632792, 1234:2211219992},
    {1114: 1291837592, 9999:1580067992, 2317:2242496792},
    {1777: 1229543192, 8888:1895687192, 2319:3725639192},
]

# create new list with new dicts
new_dict_list = [
    {k: v
     for k, v in d.items()
     if v <= filter_v}
    for d in dict_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to do what you want. Your current code is about 90% of the way there:

```
threshold = time.time()-15  # helps performance to compute this only once
dict1 = {k: v for k, v in dict1.items() if v <= threshold}
dict2 = {k: v for k, v in dict2.items() if v <= threshold}
dict3 = {k: v for k, v in dict3.items() if v <= threshold}
```

While that works, it's not especially efficient, since it needs to iterate over all the values in all the dictionaries. If a lot of the values are not going to be expired, you may want to find a better way. One idea is to put `value, key, dictionary` tuples into a heap, and pop them off until the smallest value is greater than the threshold. The `heapq` module lets you build heaps easily:

```
import heapq
from collections import counter

dict1 = {1111: 915824792, 2222:1053632792, 1234:2211219992}
dict2 = {1114: 1291837592, 9999:1580067992, 2317:2242496792}
dict3 = {1777: 1229543192, 8888:1895687192, 2319:3725639192}

heap = []
tie_breaker = counter()

for k, v in dict1.items():
    heapq.heappush(heap, (v, k, tie_breaker(), dict1))
for k, v in dict2.items():
    heapq.heappush(heap, (v, k, tie_breaker(), dict2))
for k, v in dict3.items():
    heapq.heappush(heap, (v, k, tie_breaker(), dict3))

threshold = time.time()-15
while heap[0][0] <= threshold:
    v, k, tb, dct = heapq.heappop(heap)
    del dct[k]
```

Note that if you're repeatedly doing this expiration, you don't need to repeat the `for` loops putting all the items into the heap, just add each new element to the heap at the same time you add to one of the dictionaries.